# How to insert empty record in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
----------
ID NAME
3   A
4   B
5   C
----------
```

when i delete all record, it continues after number five's record, but i want it must be insert first index of this  table. can anyone help me?

Comment: @InSane,identity column is ID, i want to insert by order of  ID (1,2,6,7,8...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `ID` column is an IDENTITY column - these will always add the next value (regardless of deletes).

The requirement to have a specific ID does sound like your application design relies on it, which is not good practice. ID fields do have gaps (which is normal) - your application shouldn't rely on them.

Regardless, here are a couple of ways of doing this:

For a one off, use [`SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY INSERT dbo.myTable ON

INSERT INTO myTable
(ID, NAME)
VALUES
(1, 'H')

SET IDENTITY INSERT dbo.myTable OFF
```

To reset the seeding, you need to use a [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) command, using `RESEED`:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('myTable', RESEED, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've got your ID column as an IDENTITY column, and you want to reset it to start again at 1, after having removed all rows from the table.

First, I'd say that having such a need (that the ID value start at 1) tends to mean there's something wrong with what you're doing - IDENTITY columns can always have gaps in the numbering, and should be treated as opaque blobs. The fact that they appear to be integers, and tend to be easy to remember, are just implementation details.

Second, if you want to do such a reset, you'd use DBCC CHECKIDENT

---

*Edit*

If you really do depend on these ID values (say, because they're also used in an application), it's a good indicator that the column shouldn't have the IDENTITY property in the first place. Unfortunately, you can't directly remove this property - you'd have to create a copy of the table without this property, copy all rows across, delete the original table, and rename the copy. Management Studio will pretend you can just remove the property, but will do what I've just described behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;
```

instead of

```
DELETE FROM mytable
```

From [TRUNCATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)

> If the table contains an identity column, the counter for that column is reset to the seed value defined for the column. If no seed was defined, the default value 1 is used. To retain the identity counter, use DELETE instead.

Comment: +1 for a smarter alternate to using DELETE + DBCC CHECKINDENT

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to restart the value of the autogenerated id column with 1 again?
if it is an IDENTITY column, you can reset the seed value with teh following command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTableNameHere', RESEED, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Databases ID feature are intended to go sure different records will NEVER have the same ID. This is not only valid for records existing at the same time, but also for new records being inserted after another one was deleted. This is extremely useful to avoid conflicts. Although it seems to sometimes break some people's sense of taste don't work around it.

If you need to assign self chosen numbers to the records add another column. Auto-indexed columns should be used all the time. The other users told you how to fiddle with the index but use this feature very careful.